# looping jquery block ui

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-blockui

i am trying to create 300 unique instances of block ui

so far this is what i have, but it is not working:

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=300;i++) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $("#q" + i).click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $("#t" + i), css: { width: '1024px' } }); 
        }); 

        $('#yes').click(function() { 
            // update the block message 
            $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" }); 

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'wait.php', 
                cache: false, 
                complete: function() { 
                    // unblock when remote call returns 
                    $.unblockUI(); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 

        $('#no').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
            return false; 
        }); 

    }); 
 }
</script>
```

modal windows

```
          <?php do { ?>
<div id="q<?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?>" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
<h3>Driver <?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?></h3><p>
<input type="button" id="yes" value="Save" style="width: 75px; height: 50px;"/> <input type="button" id="no" value="Exit" style="width: 75px; height: 50px;"/> 
</div> 
<?php } while ($row_dd31 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd31)); ?>
```

cell to activate modal window

```
 <tr height="100px" align="center">        
        <?php do { ?>
        <td style="background-color: <?php echo $row_dd1['colour']; ?>;">   
          <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>">
          <button type="submit" class="link" id="t<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?></span></button>
        </td>
        <?php } while ($row_dd1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd1)); ?>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the looping inside $(document).ready
such as,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var i=0;
  for (i=0;i<=300;i++) {
```

Comment: @jeansymolanza - does it browser return javascript error or something else ? Plus, create 300 instances, will it cause some memory exhausted on your PC ?